# How to update Map flutter/dart? Does the map updates by reference in flutter or by value?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a map:

```
{0: {0:"a",1:"b"}}
```

Now, on click of button in flutter I want to copy the map to a new key. So it should be

```
{0: {0:"a",1:"b"},1: {0:"a",1:"b"}}
```

Now, if I add a new value to key 1, it gets reflected to key 0 also.

So instead of

```
{0: {0:"a",1:"b"},1: {0:"a",1:"b",2:"c"}}
```

it becomes

```
{0: {0:"a",1:"b",2:"c"},1: {0:"a",1:"b",2:"c"}}
```

```
 Map<int,dynamic> tempMap=new HashMap();
 tempMap={...pageMap};
 var tempValue=pageMap[pageIndex];
 tempMap[(pageIndex+1)]= tempValue;
 pageMap.clear();
for (var key in tempMap.keys) {
    pageMap.putIfAbsent(key, () => tempMap[key]);
}
```

Does the map copies by reference in flutter/dart?

Answer (score 1):

In general, `var x = y` makes both x and y refer to the *same* object.  If you now send methods to x, it will also affect y, because they aren't two different objects.  So adding a value to a map referenced by y will also make that same element be visible via x.

Comment: If you want them to be completely unrelated, you can use a deep clone, which has to be constructed item by item.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be resolved with this code:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  Map getClone(Map data) {
    return data.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, v is Map ? getClone(v) : v));
  }
  
  var map1 = {0: {0:'a',1:'b'}};
  var map2 = <int, dynamic>{};
  map2[0] = getClone(map1);
  map2[1] = getClone(map1);
  print(map2);
  map2[0][0][2] = 'c';
  print(map2);
}
```

Result:

```
{0: {0: {0: a, 1: b}}, 1: {0: {0: a, 1: b}}}
{0: {0: {0: a, 1: b, 2: c}}, 1: {0: {0: a, 1: b}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, maps update by reference, not by value. But you can create a new copy of your first map and assign the copy to a second map. That way you can modify the second without modifying the first.

```dart
    final firstMap = {1: 'test'};
    var secondMap = new Map<int,dynamic>.from(firstMap);
    // You can modify secondMap now without firstMap changing
```

Have you tried updating directly the first map? It might be a simpler approach

```dart
    pageMap.putIfAbsent(pageIndex + 1, () => pageMap[pageIndex]);
```

Comment: But my firstMap is the Map which should contain all the values including the updating once. Unfortunately, all the keys are being updated. Also, as you can see in the code, I am working operations on temp map and the updating the main map

Comment: I see. Try my suggestion in the updated answer and see if it is what you need.